# Why is my variable undefined after I import it?

Tags: javascript, html, import, export

I have a function that gets the inner html of a div container.

```
function saveTab(el){

    let saveTabContainer = document.getElementById(el);
    module.exports.innerHTMLTabContainer = saveTabContainer.innerHTML; 
}
```

If I console.log the variable in this file, it returns with the appropriate value.
However, when I import it using:

```
let {innerHTMLTabContainer} = require('../public/javascripts/saveTab');
```

the value becomes undefined.

I used

```
console.log(innerHTMLTabContainer);
```

in my file that imports the innerHTMLTabContainer variable but it prints out "undefined".

Comment: _When_ is `saveTab` called? If it is called after you destructure the exports of `saveTab.js`, the value of the property will be copied into the `innerHTMLTabContainer` variable.

Comment: I have a button that has an onClick property that calls the function saveTab() and it also has a post request to a function in a different file. The post function calls for the destructuring of the export. Please let me know if you need  to see the post request function.